# Spring Security Remember Me

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I'm developing a Spring MVC web app and have configured the Spring Security to intercept all URLs and authenticate them. If the user ticks the "**remember me**", to automatically log in the user without redirecting to the login page.

Say, my login URL is

> example.com/signin

and homepage is

> example.com/home

When a user enters any URL to a valid web page (e.g. example.com/home) which needs authentication, if the **remember me is enabled**, he is directed to that specific web page without authenticating again.

But when a user enters example.com/signin, it just displays login form even if he is already authenticated and remembered.

How can I redirect him to the homepage(example.com/home) if he is an **authenticated and remmeber-me enabled** user without displaying the login page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These links might help you to implement the remember me using spring security.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-remember-me-example/

Comment: I have already implemented the remember-me. I have mentioned the exact use-case in the question. Please have a look.

Comment: are you using http security along with expressions? did you look at configuring isFullyAuthenticated()  while intercepting urls?

Answer (score 0):

I added a redirect to the controller. Please let me know if this is the correct way.

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            //if the user is already authenticated redirect him to the dashboard
            if(!(auth instanceof  AnonymousAuthenticationToken)){
                return "redirect:dashboard";
            }
            return "signin";
```